# Can I setup custom buttons on Contacts page using post install script? And remove it using uninstall script?

Tags: custom-button, postinstall

Can I setup custom buttons on Contacts page using post install script? And remove it using uninstall script?

I would like to remove the buttons administrators have setup during installation of they are to uninstall the app. Right now they have to remove all of them manually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. That would require your postinstall script to access the Metadata API or Tooling API, which [it cannot do because it has no Session Id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/326948/using-metadata-api-from-managed-package-post-install-script/326961#326961).

As I note in the linked answer, this would be fairly risky anyway - postinstall scripts are notoriously hard to debug, and mutating the org's metadata is itself complicated and high-risk.